# ProtonVPN removed from Linux but kill switch stuck on; how can I disable it?

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-mint

The latest update of protonvpn on linux resulted in a bug for me. The app wouldn't load correctly for me and I couldn't get into the settings to turn the kill switch off.

I tried to solve this by removing the app assuming that doing so would disable the kill switch and give me back internet access. However, the kill switch remained in affect. I subsequently deleted all vpn related apps I could find on my system hoping there was something left that was responsible for the VPN. However, this also did not work.

Does anyone know what might be left that could be enforcing the kill switch and/or how to disable it?

Comment: How did you install the client, to begin with, and how did you uninstall it when this issue began? Have you done something as simple as installing the client again and uninstalling it?

Comment: @music2myear I installed and uninstalled it using the apt package manager. I can't try installing it again because the kill switch is blocking my internet access

Comment: Look through 1) your iptables rules, 2) your policy routing rules in `ip rule`/`ip -6 rule`, 3) any odd configs in  `nmcli con`, 4) any unusual interfaces in `ip addr`.